# How I measure the size of kudu,s table?

Tags: apache-kudu

I am starting to work with kudu and the only way to measure the size of a table in kudu is throw the Cloudera Manager - KUDU - Chart Library - Total Tablet Size On Disk Across Kudu Replicas.
There are another way to know it throw command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the below query to get a fair idea of the size of the tables.

```
CM->Chart builder select total_kudu_on_disk_size_across_kudu_replicas where category=KUDU_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to know the size of a kudu table throw the cloudera API.

```
date=`date +%F`
curl -u $user --ssl --cacert ca-truststore.pem "https://$node:7183/api/v18/timeseries?query=select+total_kudu_on_disk_size_across_kudu_replicas+where+category%3DKUDU_TABLE&contentType=text%2Fcsv&from=$date"
```

In that case the output is in csv format.
If you want a json format:

```
curl -u $user --ssl --cacert ca-truststore.pem "https://$node:7183/api/v18/timeseries?query=select+total_kudu_on_disk_size_across_kudu_replicas+where+category%3DKUDU_TABLE&contentType=application%2Fjson&from=$date"
```